# Javascript code to same number many time 

Tags: php, javascript, html

This php generate 0    ten or less times

```
str_repeat('0', mt_rand(1, 10))
```

how can i do it in javascript in html

i want only 0 many time

Comment: Try expanding your question and fixing the title of your post.  The title and the body of your question don't seem to match.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the "join an array" hack to repeat a string, and `Math.random()` to get a random number, and any bitwise operation to round a number down, so a concise way is:

```
Array(Math.random() * 11 + 1 | 0).join('0')
```

Comment: @ShehriyarShery: If you actually tried it, maybe you'd realize that it does exactly that.

Comment: How did you get that the OP was trying to join an array out of this question? Did they change the question after you answered?

Comment: @shanabus This code does what the OP was asking. Have you tried it?

Comment: @shanabus: The array constructor, when used with a single numeric argument `n`, creates an array with `n` empty elements. So he uses it as a tricky way to repeat a string `n` times when joining it with the string. That's one of the few cases where `Array()` is better than `[]`.

Comment: Actually tried what?  Where did you get that your answer was solving his question.  The question doesn't make any sense and it definitely doesn't say anything about random numbers or joining strings.  So confused.  Props to you for being psychic

Comment: @shanabus: the OP isn't trying to join an array, but joining that array will get his string with '0' repeated a random number of times.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Function simulating PHP str_repeat()
function str_repeat(str, multiplier) {
  return new Array(multiplier + 1).join(str);
}

// Generate the string
var number_of_times = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var my_repeated_string = str_repeat('0', number_of_times);

// Put the string inside a HTML element
document.getElementById("your_element_id").innerHTML = my_repeated_string;
```

Comment: `multiplier + 1` would be much better. Why use a prefix/postfix increment when you don't actually want/need to change the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here goes...

```
var $yourString;

for(var i=0;i<10;i++) { 
  $yourString += "0"; 
}
```

Is that what you are trying to do?  Your comment on the other answer says you want to generat 0 many times, not random number.  This will do that and build it into one string.  Not sure why you would do that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `$`? It's neither PHP nor a jQuery object. Besides that you forgot `var i;` - right now you are using a global loop variable which is one of the worst things one can do in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah I typically don't use `$` with javascript but you certainly can.  PHP isn't the only language that supports it.  Good catch on the var i, but it still works - http://jsbin.com/ogeqet/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 1):

I like the array join hack (upvoted it), but here's a functional way:

```
function str_repeat (str, n) {
    n = parseInt(n, 10);

    if (--n) {
        str += str_repeat(str, n);
    }

    return str;
}


console.log(str_repeat('0', 10));  // 0000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusable parts:

```
function GetRandom(min, max)
{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function CreateRandomRepeat(text, min, max)
{
    var repeat = [];

    for (var index = 0; index < GetRandom(min, max); index++)
    {
        repeat[index] = text;
    }

    return repeat.join('');
}
```

Solution:

```
CreateRandomRepeat('0', 1, 10);
```

Comment: This has some probability issues, I think. `GetRandom` will be run each time around the loop; you should store it in a variable.

Comment: It *still* has the probability issues.